# SpringBoard Application-Kill Command

Tags: iphone

I was wondering if anybody knew how to use SpringBoard Headers and could help me to understand how I can implement this kill command into my code

```
 Class $SBApplicationController=objc_getClass("SBApplicationController") SBApplication *app=[[$SBApplicationController sharedInstance] applicationWithDisplayIdentifier:displayIdentfier]; if(app) [app kill]; –
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the application identifier you can query the PID of that application. Use the function `SBSProcessIDForDisplayIdentifier` to do this.

If you have the PID you can use the C `kill` function.